how to disable the rotate in shadcn/ui collapsible component
<CollapsibleTrigger className="w-full text-[rgb(221,103,95)]">
    <div className="flex justify-between">
        <div className="flex items-center">
            <TiTick className="p-0.5 bg-[#61b00f]  rounded-full text-white text-xl me-2" />
            <h5 className="text-black font-medium text-xl">Trip Details</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
            <IoIosArrowDown />
        </div>
   </div>

inside Trigger  i have included 2 react icons. when clicking the element the two icon get rotate. i want only one icon that have default rotation. for TiTick icon, i want to disable it.
i tried setting the open and onOpenChange of the collapsible component. but also it didn't work. the icons still rotate.

I think it should be better for you to make a reproductible example in codesandbox

then should i again post here? have you figured this out?

Yes you can post it here, most people can't help you much because they're confused by your example. Codesandbox will be appreciated

cant you just figure this issue. this is the default behaviuor of shadcn/ui collapsible component

The reason why no one tried to answer your question is because people are confused, that's why codesandbox will help make the situation clearer. You are saying something about disable rotate in Shadcn Collapsible, but when people see default shadcn collapsible component, they don't see anything rotating there.

At least, give people some screenshot. Because the original Shadcn collapsible don't even have 2 ICONS like you're saying there. I use shadcn/ui daily, but I can't comprehend your question like most people. That's why they ignore your question

inside  when we add icon  and clicked  element. then the icon rotate  180deg.
